# How to add simple textual animations to videos?

Tags: animation, effects

I want to add simple textual animations to videos, just like this one from Business Insider : https://www.facebook.com/228803477461289/videos/231065770568393/

What software do I need in order to realize this ?

I know that After Effects is capable of such things, but I'm looking for (more specialized) software with much less learning curve.

Comment: all of those could be achieved directly in your NLE or using simple templates for your NLE, if your using FCPX then Motion would be a good option otherwise AE is going to be the best bet

Comment: I'd use Premiere before I used AE, or FCPX.  Take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). Draw text with <kbd>drawtext</kbd> command. And draw semitransperent beckground under it with  <kbd>drawbox</kbd>. You can see more in [that question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15551/ffmpeg-drawtext-filter-create-transparent-background-with-text).

You can add animation of moving text  from side of video with [Expression Evaluation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).

Comment: do you know if it's possible to render the render text and video in html5 canvas, convert the merged video to webm, then use ffmpeg to produce mp4 or another format?

Answer (score 2):

This code works well now. It has several text animations with FFMpeg.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: text='First Line': fontcolor=red: fontsize=40: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=if(lt(t\,3)\,(-h+((3*h-200)*t/6))\,(h-200)/2):enable='between(t,2.9,50)',drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: text='Second Line': fontcolor=yellow: fontsize=30: x=if(lt(t\,4)\,(-w+((3*w-tw)*t/8))\,(w-tw)/2): y=(h-100)/2:enable='between(t,3.5,50)',drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: text='Third Line': fontcolor=blue: fontsize=50: x=if(lt(t\,5)\,(2*w-((3*w+tw)*t/10))\,(w-tw)/2): y=h/2:enable='between(t,4.5,50)',drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: text='Fourth Line': fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=if(lt(t\,6)\,(2*h-((3*h-100)*t/12))\,(h+100)/2):enable='between(t,5.5,50)'[out]" out.mp4`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the video, I'd say it's highly likely it was made with Adobe Premiere, Final Cut, or Adobe After Effects.  You could achieve the same thing in FFMPEG, but I doubt that's how they actually made it.

Comment: Upvoted, on this website it seems that ffmpeg is the solution to everything. It's true it can do almost anything, but when the OP asks for something easier than After Effects, ffmpeg is not really an answer

Comment: thanks for the answer. would it be possible to render the render text and video in html5 canvas, convert the merged video to webm, then use ffmpeg to produce mp4 or another format?